# Compile Python 3.4 with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have compiled SQLite3 3.8.6 and installed it to ${HOME}/opt with:

```
LDFLAGS="-L${HOME}/opt/lib" CFLAGS="-L${HOME}/opt/include" ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt
make && make install
```

I am now trying to compile Python 3.4.2 to use this version instead of the version installed for the entire system.  I do not have root access on this system.  To compile Python, I am using:

```
LDFLAGS="-L${HOME}/opt/lib" CFLAGS="-L${HOME}/opt/include" ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt
make && make install
```

I was able to compile Python 3.3.5 with my newer version if SQLite3, but these same steps don't seem to work for me for 3.4.2.

How can I compile Python 3.4.2 to include my version of SQLite 3.8.6 which is located in ${HOME}/opt?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** It compiles & installs OK except for the fact that is using the older, system version of sqlite3 instead of the version that I compiled & installed myself.

Comment: Try to get some output during the install to see all that it is doing and it is not pointing to a wrong place

Comment: Are you sure it uses the system version and not its own copy?

Comment: @CL: Yes. I did a `find . | grep sqlite3.h` inside the Python-3.4.2 source directory and it did not return any files.

Comment: This same issue has me baffled too. There is no system libsqlite3-dev package installed, only the runtime; I've built and installed sqlite3 3.8.8 in /usr/local, configured and built Python 3.4.2 which still reports '3.7.9' as the `sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is also the option of pre-linking your custom Python build with your own-built sqlite3. (I had the same issue: the custom python was using the system-provided sqlite3, completely ignoring the sqlite3 I built).

Prefix your `configure` and `make` commands with:

```
LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/opt/lib configure LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/opt/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/opt/include" …
LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/opt/lib make
```

so that the built `python3` by default is linked to your sqlite3.
This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.  Now, there is no need to use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc.

Comment: As an alternative, adding `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/opt/lib` (a linker flag that tells `ld` to write `$HOME/opt/lib` into the runtime path of any binaries it makes) to `LDFLAGS` will (robustly and permanently) accomplish the same thing, at least if your compiler is GCC. Sources: [here](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html) and [here](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import platform,sqlite3
print("Oper Sys : %s %s" % (platform.system(), platform.release()))
print("Platform : %s %s" % (platform.python_implementation(),platform.python_version()))
print("SQLite   : %s" % (sqlite3.sqlite_version))
```

When I run this code, the output contains the system's version of sqlite3:

```
Oper Sys : Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
Platform : CPython 3.4.2
SQLite   : 3.7.13
```

After installing sqlite v3.8.6 under ${HOME}/opt{include,lib} and setting this in my .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${HOME}/opt/lib"
```

I get my desired result:

```
Oper Sys : Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
Platform : CPython 3.4.2
SQLite   : 3.8.6
```

Notice the SQLite version changes from `3.7.13` to `3.8.6`

Comment: hi, I followed your method here by doing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt"` in my `~/.bash_profile`, where `/usr/local/opt` is the directory that contains all the symlinks to homebrew installed libraries including `sqlite3`. However, after restart my bash, it still gives me the system-wide version of `sqlite3` in Python. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try using the method in the other answer, by @tzot.

Comment: Worked for me, but note for others: Note the difference between `sqlite3.sqlite_version` (refers to SQLite library) and `sqlite3.version` (refers to the python module version that imports sqlite3, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

Hi for me helped this:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
tar xvf sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
mv /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3.7
cp /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3280000/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3
cp /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3280000/.libs/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
cp /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3280000/.libs/libsqlite3.so.0 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
```