# Building a Python 3 version using pyenv while linked to a custom sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyenv

I installed `sqlite3` using `homebrew` in order to use the newer version than the system-wide version supplied by OS X.

Now I want to install Python 3.4.3 using `pyenv` and guide the build process to use the `sqlite3` installed by `homebrew` rather than the OS X's version.

I found this: [Compile Python 3.4 with sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261080/compile-python-3-4-with-sqlite3), and tried adapting it to work with `pyenv`, but failed - the installed Python 3.4.3 still links with the OS X `sqlite3`. The command I tried:

```
env LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/opt" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" pyenv install 3.4.3
```

What is the correct way of doing it with `pyenv`?

Comment: it's a little odd that some of your special paths point to usr-local-**opt** while another to usr-local-**include**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/tree/master/plugins/python-build#special-environment-variables

Best match:

> `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` and `PYTHON_MAKE_OPTS` allow you to specify configure and make options for buildling CPython. These variables will be passed to Python only, not any dependent packages (e.g. `libyaml`).

More general, if needed:

> `CONFIGURE_OPTS` lets you pass additional options to `./configure`

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried utilizing `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS` and `PYTHON_MAKE_OPTS`, but they resulted in compiling errors during the Python installation via `pyenv`.