# Upgrade SQLite version inside a python3.6 venv without root or affecting the global packages

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-venv

First off, I know similar questions have been answered, but I can't find any solutions for my particular constraints. If there is one, please point me to it.

I'm trying to start a django project. However, I can't run the development server. The problem seems to be the SQLite version. I have 3.7.17 installed, django requires 3.9 or later. So I need to upgrade it. The problem is I'm using one machine from many, used by multiple developers all working on different projects, but sharing the same global python packages. So whatever changes I need to make, need to be inside my venv. And I don't have root access on the machine. Also, I don't plan on using SQLite as the DB for the project, so if that means I can somehow bypass this requirement, that would be fine as well. However, I assume, in that case I'll need to somehow transfer the django admin app to my DB of choice as well?

Note: I'm quite new to web development or programming in general, so a dumbed down explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "_I don't plan on using SQLite as the DB for the project_" does that mean you won't be using Sqlite for development and will be using some other DB? Just configure your settings for Django to use that DB. Read the documentation a bit: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/ Also read [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup) from the official tutorial.

Comment: If you really need to do this, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68589898/5320906) may help.  But the latest version appears to be 3.36 (judging from the [downloads page](https://sqlite.org/download.html) so perhaps you should double-check the requirements.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's a good answer you linked to keep in my backpocket, should I ever need it, but right now the problem with it seems to be the third step. I would have to change the headers throughout the django library if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm planning on using mongoDB for my app, so it does seem best to just configure Django to use this from the get go. I'll look into the docs and the guide. Thanks.

Comment: @raghavj mongoDB is not one of the officially supported databases by Django, although if you do want to use it there are some 3rd party packages a popular one being [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo). Although I would say using it can get a bit tricky since it has some long unresolved bugs forcing people to use workarounds.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I was able to at least run the dev server by just commenting out the DATABASES definition in settings.py for the project. I'm planning on using mongoEngine. The downside being that I'll have to build default django apps like admin from scratch to use mongoDB. But it works. Thanks for the help!